# Drawing line to link treeview node of one treeview to treeview node of another treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, drawing, paint

How is it possible to draw a line to link treeview node to another treeview node

> link should be shown in from

Comment: This is not really possible. You could try to draw two lines or overlay both TVs with a transparent window, which would kill interactivity.. Will you need interactivity?

Comment: OK tell me how that can be done . so that I will achieve something nearby that

Comment: How much are  you willing to pay for this? in US dollars, please.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `WinForms` `TreeViews` are special.

- For one they don't have a `Paint` event, so it is not possible to draw on them.
  (You can subclass them though, see the update below..!)
- Secondly you can't nest a transparent control in them. You can nest it but it won't be transparent..)

So drawing onto the `TreeView` seems to be imposible. But maybe it is not what you want anyway..?

Let's instead draw a line **between** two `TreeViews`, connection two `TreeNodes` n1 and n2.

Let's place the TVs onto a `Panel panel1`.

For testing I create two class level `Points p1 and p2`:

```
Point p1 = Point.Empty;
Point p2 = Point.Empty;
```

In the `Panel's Paint` event we draw the line:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Firebrick, p1, p2);
}
```

For testing I set the `Points` in the `NodeMouseClick` event:

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode n1 = e.Node;
    // for testing I search for a corresponding node:
    TreeNode n2 = treeView2.Nodes.Find(n1.Name, true).First();
    // for testing I select the node:
    treeView2.SelectedNode = n2;
    // top left points in the node:
    p1 = n1.Bounds.Location;
    p2 = n2.Bounds.Location;
    // add the offset of the treviews:
    p1.Offset(treeView1.Left, treeView1.Top);
    p2.Offset(treeView2.Left, treeView2.Top);
    // trigger the paint event;
    panel1.Invalidate();
}
```

Note that the above code connects the upper left points of the nodes.

To connect the outsides of the respective lines you could calculate the points like this:

```
p1 = new Point(treeView1.Right, n1.Bounds.Top + n1.Bounds.Height / 2 + treeView1.Top);
p2 = new Point(treeView2.Left, n2.Bounds.Top + n2.Bounds.Height / 2 + treeView2.Top);
```

[image]

**Update:**  Big thanks to Larstech for his info about overriding the WndProc method and catching WM_PAINT. I tend to block out WndProc  ;-)

Using this technique it is indeed possible to draw onto a TreeView:

[image]

This screenshot uses a `TreeView` **subclass** and paints three lines: One on each TV and one on the Panel below.

Here is the `TreeView` class:

```
class PTreeView : TreeView
{
    public bool IsLeft { get; set; }
    public int  BorderWidth { get; private set; }
    private float slope { get; set; }
    private Point Pt { get; set; }

    public PTreeView()     {       }

    public void markNode(TreeNode node, float slope_)
    {
        if (this.IsLeft ) Pt = 
         new Point(node.Bounds.Right, node.Bounds.Top + node.Bounds.Height / 2);
        else Pt = new Point(node.Bounds.Left, node.Bounds.Top + node.Bounds.Height / 2);
        slope = slope_;
        BorderWidth = (this.Width - this.ClientRectangle.Width) / 2;
    }

    internal const int WM_PAINT = 0xF;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == WM_PAINT)
        {
            Graphics G = this.CreateGraphics();
            G.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            int px = IsLeft ? this.ClientRectangle.Width : 0;
            int py = (int)(Pt.Y + slope * (Pt.X - px));
            Point p0 = new Point(px, py);

            G.DrawLine(Pens.Coral, Pt, p0);
        }
    }
  }
```

It exposes a bool to set if the TV is left or right of the other one and its `BorderWidth`, and a method `markNode` that determines which node should be connected with the lines and what slope the line has.

The `NodeMouseClick` has been expanded a little:

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode n1 = e.Node;
    TreeNode n2 = treeView2.Nodes.Find(n1.Name, true).First();
    treeView2.SelectedNode = n2;

    p1 = new Point(
          treeView1.Left + n2.Bounds.Left + n1.Bounds.Width + treeView1.BorderWidth,
          treeView1.Top  + n1.Bounds.Top + n1.Bounds.Height / 2 + treeView1.BorderWidth);
    p2 = new Point(
          treeView2.Left + n2.Bounds.Left + treeView2.BorderWidth,
          treeView2.Top  + n2.Bounds.Top + n2.Bounds.Height / 2 + treeView2.BorderWidth);

    float slope = -1f * (p2.Y - p1.Y) / (p2.X - p1.X);
    treeView1.markNode(n1, slope);
    treeView2.markNode(n2, slope);

    panel1.Invalidate();
    treeView1.Invalidate();
    treeView2.Invalidate();
}
```

It now calculates the slope and calls both `markNode` and `Invalidate` on both treeviews..

No real changes in the Panel Paint:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Coral, p1, p2);
}
```

Comment: Technically, you *can* paint in the TreeView control.  Just override the WndProc method and look for the WM_PAINT message, then use the Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle).  I won't claim it's pretty. Just sayin'.

Comment: @Lars: Thanks a lot for the hint. Yes, that seems to work. Not sure if I would use it, but it is good to know..