# Draw a line between two pictureboxes that have fixed positions c# windows form

Tags: c#

I am working on a project where I should draw a line between two picture box.

Please note that I know how to get the coordinates of each picture box, but I don't know what method to use to draw a line between them.

Here is my code so far:

```
Point p1, p2;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            int x = pictureBox1.Location.X;
            MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
            p1.X = pictureBox1.Location.X;
            p1.Y = pictureBox1.Location.Y;
            p2.X = pictureBox2.Location.X;
            p2.Y = pictureBox2.Location.Y;
        }
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: [This example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862076/drawing-line-to-link-treeview-node-of-one-treeview-to-treeview-node-of-another-t/31865490#31865490) of drawing a line between two TreeViews should help. (Part one only!)

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help you

```
pointArray[iNumberofClicks].X = e.X;
pointArray[iNumberofClicks].Y = e.Y;
Pen PenSpikes = new Pen(Color.Green);
SolidBrush solidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
iNumberofClicks++;
if (iNumberofClicks > 1)
{
  Point[] CurrentpointArray = new Point[iNumberofClicks];

  for (int i = 0; i < iNumberofClicks; i++)
  {
    CurrentpointArray[i].X = pointArray[i].X;
    CurrentpointArray[i].Y = pointArray[i].Y;
  }

  Bitmap canvas = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
  Graphics offScreenDC = Graphics.FromImage(canvas);
  // New line!
  offScreenDC.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, new Point());
  offScreenDC.DrawLines(PenSpikes, CurrentpointArray);

  pictureBox1.Image = canvas;
  offScreenDC.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        points.Add(e.Location);
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{enter code here
    if (points.Count > 1)
       e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Black, points.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: I don't want to click on the picture box, I already have the 2 picture boxes placed, I just want to draw a line between them.